# When Barry time travels one day in the past, where is the Barry of that timeline?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

The title says it all: When Barry time travels one day in the past, where is the Barry of that timeline?

Comment: Welcome to the site; please take the [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how things work around here. I've adjusted your title to make it show up in the list as something people might have an interest in. However, there isn't anything to the body. To avoid downvotes or deletion, you might consider explaining what episode you were watching when the question came to you, and why you think it's important.

Comment: I have to admit when I saw the episode I presume the OP is speaking of this week I wondered the same thing. 
Flash is running to the morgue and sees an "echo" of himself.... later tries to stop a tidal wave, travels back to see his previous self seeing him, stops confused, then continues on to the morgue... the earlier flash THAT HE JUST SAW is nowhere to be found/seen/spoken to by the rest of the team. So was that explained someplace that I missed? I have only gotten as far as that episode in the series.

Answer (score -2):

The title say it all: one day in the past. ;)
(Clarification as to which Barry you're referring to would be helpful, as would an episode as a reference point)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.